# Access rules of bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket.org

I have a question about the access rules of BitBucket.

Is it possible to create a repository "private", only people who have a link can access and read it ?

I'd like to mention the url of a private repository in a scientific paper and submit this paper to a conference. I don't know in advance the e-mails of the reviewers to invite them to a private repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create private repositories in Bitbucket, but a private repository is one that only your users can log into, not one that's publicly accessible without a login but behind a URL that's not published, which seems to be what you want. So I don't think you can do what you want with Bitbucket.

Comment: I don't know if there is another solution. With https://github.com/ this is isn't possible also!